# Getting AWS error while creating new play project (activator)

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I am trying to develop a sample play framework applicaiton but when I have downloaded it and tried executing it I am getting below error related to amazon cloud web services(AWS).

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials

Command I am executing :

`activator new my-first-app play-java`

I have downloaded `activator-1.3.7-minimal` and it has only 3 files :

1. activator
2. activator.bat
3. activator-launch-1.3.7.jar

I am wondering why it is trying to get AWS.